# Hide v-html while loading

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I've got a `v-html` in my code:

```html
<div v-html="store.detailHTML"></div>
```

In a slower network speed, it took a few seconds to render the HTML content. Until that, I only see plain text. Is it possible to show the div itself when the HTML is rendered?

Comment: Add conditional rendering like `<div v-if="store.detailHTML" v-html="store.detailHTML"></div>` or `<div v-html="store.detailHTML || '<span>Loading ...</span>'"></div>`

Comment: First off, why are you using `v-html`? Then, you could make use of a `v-if` + `v-else`.